# No rule to make target `libbrcmEGL.so', needed by `HelloTriangle'

Tags: c++, linux, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to cross-compile an OpenGLES2.0 example HelloTriangle using VisualGDB for the RaspberryPi 3 running Raspbian lite.

I assume I was able to include the libraries `libbrcmEGL.so` and `libbrcmGLESv2.so` correctly in my `CMakeLists.txt` file
because instead of giving me these errors:

```
c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLIBGLES
c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLIBEGL`
```

It gives me these errors

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `libbrcmEGL.so', needed by `HelloTriangle'.  Stop.`
```

This is my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.7)
project(HelloTriangle)
set(LIBRARIES_FROM_REFERENCES "")
add_executable(HelloTriangle HelloTriangle.cpp esShapes.c esTransform.c esUtil.c esShader.c)
include_directories(include)
target_link_libraries(HelloTriangle ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libbrcmGLESv2.so ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libbrcmEGL.so "${LIBRARIES_FROM_REFERENCES}")
```

I don't understand what else it needs to make the target. Looking around stack overflow, I saw suggestions to add

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/opt/vc/lib/)
```

I also tried

```
target_link_libraries(HelloTriangle /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so "${LIBRARIES_FROM_REFERENCES}")
```

I also checked that I have these libraries in my sysroot in:

```
C:\SysGCC\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot
```

I still get the same error:

I need some help figuring out what is missing from my CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

Changed to `target_link_libraries(HelloTriangle ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libbrcmEGL.so "${LIBRARIES_FROM_REFERENCES}")` and it compiled